# How to solve this error JSONEditor is not defined ESlint

Tags: javascript, angularjs, eslint

I have a JSON Editor and it works correctly but ESlint keeps giving me this error

> 'JSONEditor' is not defined

My code exists inside an angularJS 1.7 component.

```
this.$onInit = function () {
    var container = $document[0].getElementById('jsoneditor');
    var editor = new JSONEditor(container, { mode: 'code' }, json);
    // code to use the editor 
};
```

Nothing complicated only ESLint not happy with it.

Comment: Use `window.JSONEditor`

Answer (score 1):

ESLint does not know anything about the existence of the class within your code.
You can just skip it or comment it out of your code or add it to exceptions

Answer (score 1):

I added this line and it solved the problem

```
/* global JSONEditor */
```